# why the preview in storyboard is different from running in the simulator

Tags: ios, storyboard, size-classes

I was testing the same `UIImageView` can show different image in different simulator. So I add a `UIImageView` in the `Main.storyboard`, and add 4 constains so that the Image was the center of the screen. Then I import a picture(A) in the `Images.xcassets` and named it "person".

In the attributes inspector I selected **Width:Regular & Height:Regular**, then I drag another picture(B) into the position(1x[++]).

[image: first example]

---

Now the result in **the preview isn't match the running in the simulator(iPad)**. There is no warning or conflict in constrains, I don't understand.

[image: first example]

Comment: Is simulator showing you the desired result?

Comment: Delete your App from the Simulator and rebuild it again.

Comment: @the_UB is not the desired result in preview

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff the Simulator is working alright.the question is the preview isn't match the Simulator

Comment: Its fine if simulator is showing the correct result. Sometimes it happens with previews.

Comment: right? I always think the preview is the copy with the Simulator,Never think something wrong happened with previews.@Irfan